# url rewriting add prefix www with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, url-rewriting

I created my website with symfony and I want to rewrite the URL.
The url apprears like this: **domain.com/web/**

I removed the **web/** by adding this code .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This worked perfectly.

My target now is to add the **www.** prefix. I solved that by adding this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The result is almost OK. In fact,

- the URL **domain.com** becomes **www.domain.com**   (perfect!!!)
- the URL **domain.com/something/** becomes **www.domain.com/something/** (perfect!!!)
- the URL **domain.com/web/** stays the same (it's the only URL that does not change)

Is there any idea to redirect **domain.com/web/** to  **www.domain.com**???

Thanks...

Comment: Please post the final rule set you are currently using. This appears to be a problem with order of execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is caused by the condition that existing files won't be rewritten:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: with or without this condition **RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f**, the result is still the same!!!